# Variance of A sin(Fx)+Bx, and correlation

Tags: statistics, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral, variance

I was wondering about the statistical variance of $A\sin(F x)+ Bx$, and the covariance (or correlation) between $A_{1} \sin(F_{1} x) + B_{1} x$ and
$A_{2} \sin(F_{2} x) + B_{2} x$, assuming that $x$ is uniformly distributed in $[0, U]$, and $A, A_1, A_2, F, F_1, F_2, B, U$ are constants.

How can I proceed to compute these quantities in the simplest way?

Comment: $X$ is uniform where? We need an interval to start.

Comment: uniform on [0, U]

Comment: Have you tried writing down the definition of the variance/covariance? That should give you an integral, right? Have you tried to evaluate the integral?

Comment: I have not succeeded, as the definition seemed difficult to apply: hoping in some simpler way. Note that there is probably no need to refer to a distribution, it could be simply a Lebesgue measure.

Comment: At an intuitive level, I would expect the correlation to be close to the geometric mean of the B's.

Comment: The integrals here are easy to compute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to simplify your notation some. I will have capital letters refer to random variables and lowercase letters refer to the parameters. To that end, suppose $X \sim \mathcal{U}(0, u)$ (that is, $X$ follows a uniform distribution on $[0, u]$). Consider the random variable $Y = a\sin(\lambda X) + bX.$ I'll leave it to you to compute the variance, knowing that
$$\sigma_X ^2 = E(X^2) - (E(X))^2$$

(hint: integrate by parts). Once you have the variance, now use the correlation formula
$$\rho_{X, Y} = \frac{\mathrm{Cov}(X, Y)}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y}$$

where the covariance is a double integral in this case, i.e.

$$ \mathrm{Cov}(X, Y) =E\left[ (X - E(X))(Y - E(Y) \right].$$

This, again, may require parts.

Comment: Yes, thank you. With your formula above, the variance seems easier to compute (with respect to the classic definition). I need to see how to do the correlation which seems a bit more complicated :-) Perhaps a similar simplification can be done for that too by using mixed moments ...